# Android get variable in layout preview with data binding?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-databinding

Is it possible to see in layout preview in Android Studio window an int in view's marginLeft? Here is what I'm trying:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="doorLeft"
        type="Integer" />
</data>

(...)

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/castle_main_door"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@{doorLeft}"
     android:src="@drawable/castle_main_door2" />
```

I am setting this value in my Activity like this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

(...)

binding.setDoorLeft(300);
```

But in layout preview it is not shown (marginLeft is 0).

**I am emphasising once more, I want to have this variable in LAYOUT PREVIEW.**

Answer (score 2):

`layout-preview` doesn't support variables in databinding. So you can't apply changes from your code to `layout-preview`

In case your want to preview how large is your margin, use `tools:layout_marginLeft="your margin values"`

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/castle_main_door"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="@{doorLeft}"
 android:src="@drawable/castle_main_door2"
 tools:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
```